# DVD-ROM gets disabled after each restart

Tags: windows-7, dvd

I have the following problem, everytime I restart my computer I found my DVD drive disabled. So I have to go to the Device Manager and manually enable it again, after that everything works fine.

**EDIT**

I am not aware of any recent changes (I don't think I installed new software in past few weeks). Also I don't use DVD drive much so I am actually not sure how long I have this problem. Only program which comes to my mind is `Daemon Tools` which I have installed like half a year ago but it could be root of my problem.

My DVD-ROM is `MATSHITA DVD-RAM UJ8A2ASW` and motherboard is `ASUSTeK U46SV`.

Where could be the problem?

Comment: What changed in the environment recently? Windows Update? Any new software (e.g. iTunes)?

Comment: What brand & model is the drive and what brand & model is the motherboard?